# How to avoid timeout on a Redis LockRelease call

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I'm consistently getting the following timeout exception when I attempt to release a redis lock. I'm using Azure Redis with StackExchange.Redis version 1.1.603. The exception I get is as follows. I looked at the link included in the exception error, but I don't see anything that pertains to this scenario.

```
Unexpected lock release failure on lock key 1ea47191-85e6-4f89-ad20-be700d643d6a-ProbeIdsLock on machine ELITEBOOK. Timeout performing EX
EC, inst: 0, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 3, qu: 1, qs: 2, qc: 0, wr: 1, wq: 1, in: 101, ar: 0, clientName: ELITEBOOK, IOCP: (Busy=1,Free=
999,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=1022,Min=4,Max=1023), Local-CPU: 100% (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side
 issues that can cause timeouts: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/tree/master/Docs/Timeouts.md) -    at StackExchange.Redis
.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3
ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2044
         at StackExchange.Redis.RedisTransaction.Execute(CommandFlags flags) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3ae0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redi
s\StackExchange\Redis\RedisTransaction.cs:line 51
         at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.LockRelease(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, CommandFlags flags) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\3a
e0647004edff78\StackExchange.Redis\StackExchange\Redis\RedisDatabase.cs:line 838
         at ENow.RedisCache.RedisConnection.LockRelease(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, CommandFlags commandFlags)
         at ENow.RedisCache.MonitoringCache.LockRelease(RedisKey lockKey, RedisValue token)
```

The code essentially looks as follows. The Redis calls are wrapped to make it easier to eventually write unit tests.

```
        public async Task<bool> AddProbeStatus(string tenantId, ProbeStatus probeStatus)
    {
        probeStatus.ProbeId.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty("probeStatus.ProbeId");
        var key = $"{tenantId}-ProbeIds";
        var lockKey = key + "Lock";
        RedisValue token = Environment.MachineName;
        var lockAquired = false;
        var finalResult = false;
        var retryCount = 0;
        try
        {
            while (!lockAquired)
            {
                retryCount++;
                lockAquired = _redisConnection.LockTake(lockKey, token, TimeSpan.MaxValue);

                if (lockAquired)
                {
                    _log.LogDebug($"Probe status lock aquired for tenant {tenantId}");

                    var result = await _redisConnection.StringGetAsync(key);

                    List<ProbeStatus> probeStatuses;
                    if (result == RedisValue.Null)
                    {
                        _log.LogDebug(
                            $"No probe status cache found for tenant {tenantId}. Adding probe {probeStatus.ProbeId} to cache.");
                        probeStatus.LastCheckinTimeInUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        probeStatuses = new List<ProbeStatus> {probeStatus};
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        probeStatuses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProbeStatus>>(result);
                        var existingProbeStatus = probeStatuses.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProbeId == probeStatus.ProbeId);
                        if (existingProbeStatus != null)
                        {
                            _log.LogDebug(
                                $"Updating last checkin time for probe {probeStatus.ProbeId} for tenant {tenantId} in probe status cache.");
                            existingProbeStatus.LastCheckinTimeInUtc = probeStatus.LastCheckinTimeInUtc;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _log.LogDebug(
                                $"Adding new probe {probeStatus.ProbeId} for tenant {tenantId} to probe status cache.");
                            probeStatuses.Add(probeStatus);
                        }
                    }
                    var probeStatusesAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(probeStatuses);
                    finalResult = await _redisConnection.StringSetAsync(key, probeStatusesAsJson);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (retryCount > MaxRetryCount)
                    {
                        var errorMessage =
                            $"Retry count exceeded while attempting to aquire lock in probe status cache for tenant {tenantId}";
                        _log.LogError(errorMessage);
                        throw new Exception(errorMessage);
                    }
                    _log.LogWarning($"Couldn't aquire lock in probe status cache for tenant {tenantId}. Waiting {DefaultRetrySeconds} seconds before retrying");
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DefaultRetrySeconds));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.LogError($"Failed to set probe IDs for tenant {tenantId}. {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockAquired)
            {
                if(!LockRelease(lockKey, token))
                {
                    finalResult = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _log.LogDebug($"Lock not aquired for key {lockKey} on machine {token}");
            }
        }
        return finalResult;
    }
```

This code is called from an ASP.NET 5 RC1 WebAPI. If I run it in Azure or locally I get the timeout. However, I have a simple XUnit integration test that exercises this same code and it runs with no exception against the same Azure hosted Redis Cache. Could it be there is some incompatibility with ASP.NET 5 RC1 and StackExchange.Redis version 1.1.603? It's odd that this issue consistently happens in the WebAPI. It's not intermittent in any way. Also, it always succeeds using the integration test, so it feels like there is something else going here and that the timeout is just a red herring.